# Re-arranging span elements in a div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get an asterix "*" to appear directly above the "pp", however if I try to insert this in a span adjacent to the span containing the "pp" or directly after the price, it does not sit above as desired..

Can somebody please help? My html is below

```html
<div class="fist-div">
    <span>
         <span data-bind="text: '£' + price">£731*</span>
         <small>pp</small>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Above ? Like using `<sup>` tag ?

Comment: Hey there and welcome! We'll definitely help you as best we can but you haven't given us enough info to do that yet. Go ahead to a website that allows you to submit code (hint: [jsfiddle.com](http://www.jsfiddle.com)). There you can paste your HTML and CSS which you can share to show us what is happening and it'll help us visualise what you're trying to do too ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sup` tag to do this. Try this.

CSS & HTML

```css
sup{color:red}
```

```html
      <div class="fist-div">
       <span>
        <span data-bind="text: '£' + price">£731</span>
        <small>pp<sup>*</sup></small>
       </span>
   </div>
```

You can rearrange it wherever you want * to appear.   Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `*` directly above pp, you need to adjust the position.

```css
.first-div small {
  position: relative;
  left: -10px;
  top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first-div">
  <span>
    <span data-bind="text: '£' + price">£731*</span>
    <small>pp</small>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this..

```css
sup {
  color: green;
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fist-div">
  <span>
     <span data-bind="text: '£' + price">£731<sup>*</sup></span>
  <small>pp</small>

  </span>
</div>
```